# Regular expression - Allow dashes anywhere inside a phone number

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression :

```
^(1?)(-| ?)(\()?([0-9]{3})(\)|-| |\)-|\) )?([0-9]{3})(-| )?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4})$
```

I want to allow dashes ("-") anywhere inside the string.
what is the best way to do it ?

Source:
http://www.regxlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1497

Comment: Can you post some valid and slightly invalid examples what you RE matches? That would definitely help to get on with it.

Comment: How many digits is the phonenumber? Are you going to use the regex for validation or for something else?

Comment: I'm validating a US phone number. The phone number is 10 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the best would be changing parts like

```
[0-9]{3}
```

into

```
(?:[0-9]-?){3}
```

This means there are 3 numbers, each may be followed by a dash. If you want to allow multiple dashes there, change `?` to `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply treat "-" as digits by changing `[0-9]` to `[0-9-]`

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with regex.

1. Strip out everything that's not a digit or a dash.
2. Copy the stripped string to a temp var.
3. Strip out the dashes.
4. Ensure that you have 10 digits left over.
5. If so, use the temp var as your value.